# RSA Decryption in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I know how to decrypt data in .Net using RSA. But now I want to do that in xamarin without using BouncyCastle dll. This is how I did it in .Net

```
IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), iv);
cipher.Init(false, PrivateKey);
this.SecretKey = cipher.ProcessBlock(encryptedSecretKey, 0, encryptedSecretKey.Length);
```

I this the encryptedSecretKey was 256 bytes and after decryption SecretKey becomes 32 bytes. I think the SHA256 value is removed...But plz suggest me what should I do to achieve same without using BouncyCastle in xamarin. I need resultant bytes as 32

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a cross-platform compatible library like BouncyCastle you will have to somehow separate the code for each platform. Either using #if **ANDROID** || **IOS** or having separate projects. 
What is your problem with BouncyCastle exactly?